# What does this mean: sizeof(0[a])

Tags: c, arrays

When I read asterisk source code, I found a code line like this:

> ```
> #define ARRAY_LEN(a) (size_t) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(0[a]))
> ```

I often use `a[0]` or `(*a)`, but they use `(0[a])`. Could you please help me explain more clearly about this?

Comment: A good question IMO. Pointer arithmetics is an horrible pitfall in C, and understanding better how it works is a good idea.

Comment: This has many dups here already.

Comment: Inside a macro this actually saves 2 characters of typing: `a[0]` could be incorrect, so the options are `(a)[0]` or `0[a]`. Of course there is also `*(a)`.

Comment: [With C arrays, why is it the case that `a[5] == 5[a]`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/381542/995714)

Comment: @M.M I would strongly recommend programmers who don't like typing to change career. Programming involves a whole lot of typing. Programmers who obfuscate their programs into unreadable crap, in order to save typing 2 characters should change career anyway, or have someone force them to change career.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a[0]` is translated by the compiler as `*(a+0)`. `0[a]` is translated as `*(0+a)`. Hence, `a[0]` and `0[a]` are equivalent.

From the C99 standard:

> **6.5.2.1 Array subscripting**
>
> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets `[]` is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator `[]` is that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are **symmetric**
and that means `arr[idx]` and `idx[arr]` are completely same to the compiler.

Therefore, `sizeof(idx[arr])` is the byte size of the *idx*'th element of the array *arr*